# Send Email using nodemailer

Tags: reactjs, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer to send email in ReactJS. 
I'm refering code from `https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp` and do the same. 
But i got error: net.isIP is not a function

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: "xuanle.khtn@gmail.com",
        pass: "********",
      },
    });

    var mailOptions = {
      from: "xuanle.khtn@gmail.com",
      to: "leanhxuan_t59@hus.edu.vn",
      subject: "Sending Email using Node.js",
      text: "That was easy!",
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
```

When i run app, i received the message from browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: net.isIP is not a function
at Object.push../node_modules/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js.module.exports.resolveHostname (index.js:36)
at SMTPConnection.connect (index.js:299)
at index.js:263
at index.js:70
at run (setImmediate.js:40)
at runIfPresent (setImmediate.js:69)
at onGlobalMessage (setImmediate.js:109)
```

> I'm newbie so i don't have any idea with this error. 
> How to
>   resolve this problem?

Comment: What version of nodejs are you using ?

Comment: @Crikxi I'm using node 12.16.2

Comment: Are you sure you're credentials are correct. Plus you just specify a port for gmail. Get an application password instead of using the real one.

Comment: @AvivLo I'm sure that my credentials are correct, both auth, from and to, they are existed email

Comment: You need to do this on your server, not on the front end.  Set this functionality up in one of your routes or somewhere on your server.  The client doesn't haven't access to SMTP server so you should set it up on the back end

Comment: Is the password the normal password or the application password. I've add part of my code from a project that's working. Perhaps it can help you a bit.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to run nodemailer on the client-side? It won't work and Ita not secure.

Comment: Yeah, I'm coding on front-end source. Nodemailer does not support client side, doesn't it?

Comment: @MichaelMayo I don't have backend, is there different way to send email from ReactJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodemailer module won't work on the client side and it's not secure to use it there.

If it's at the back-end, the error is basically saying that it has some troubles resolving the hostname.

So your code should look like the following if you're using gmail:

```
 ​//​Create transport + auth​
    ​let​ transporter ​=​ ​mailer​.​createTransport​({
        host​:​ ​"​smtp.gmail.com​"​,
        port​:​ ​587​,
        auth​:​ {
            user​:​ ​creds​.​userName​,
            pass​:​ ​creds​.​password​
        }
    });
```

Remember to setup an application password for nodemailer instead of using your real password.

This is the working code that grabbed our of my project.

Maybe it can serve as a reference of some sort.

```
​'​use strict​'​
​//​Dependencies​
​const​ ​mailer​ ​=​ ​require​(​'​nodemailer​'​);
​//​Credentials​
​const​ ​creds​ ​=​ ​require​(​'​./creds/gmail​'​);
​//​Mailing Function​
​const​ ​mailFunc​ ​=​ (​subject​, ​recipient​, ​msg​, ​cbMail​) ​=>​ {

    ​//​Create transport + auth​
    ​let​ transporter ​=​ ​mailer​.​createTransport​({
        host​:​ ​"​smtp.gmail.com​"​,
        port​:​ ​587​,
        auth​:​ {
            user​:​ ​creds​.​userName​,
            pass​:​ ​creds​.​password​
        }
    });

    ​//​Create the message object​
    ​let​ message ​=​ {
        from​:​ ​'​example@gmail.com​'​,
        to​:​ recipient,
        subject​:​ subject,
        text​:​ msg,
        ​//​ html: "<p>HTML version of the message</p>"​
    };

    ​//​Send mail​
    ​transporter​.​sendMail​(message)
        .​then​(​res​ ​=>​ {
            ​cbMail​(​res​.​response​);
        })
        .​catch​(​err​ ​=>​ {
            ​cbMail​(err);
        })
}

​//​Export the module​
​module​.​exports​ ​=​ { mailFunc }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing host and port in createTransport object:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
      pass: testAccount.pass // generated ethereal password
    }
  });
```